# div float over div over text - NOT GOOD

Tags: html, css

Alright guys thanks for helping me with the 100% height problem. it works now..

Now i have another problem.

My html:

```
<div id="menu"> Test </div>

<div id="content">

    <div id="submnu">
    Submenu 1 <br />
    <br />
    Submenu 2 <br />
    <br />
    Submenu 3 <br />
    <br />
    Submenu 4 <br />
    <br />
    Submenu 5 <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    LOGIN FORM<br />
    <br />
    <form method="POST" action="...php">
    Username:<br />
    <input type="text" name="username" style="width: 200px; border: #373c39 double 2px;" /><br /><br />
    Password:<br />
    <input type="password" name="password" style="width: 200px; border: #373c39 double 2px;" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>


    </div>

    <div id="txt">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <img src="images/producttest.png" border="0" />
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top: 50px;">
    Productomschrijving: <br />
    <p>

    <div id="scimg">
    Winkelwagen<br />
    </div>

    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.<br />
    Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. 
    <br />Donec eu libero sit amet quam egesta semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. 
    <br />Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. 
    <br />Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. 
    <br /><br />
    Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci,<br />
    sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.<br />
    Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue,<br />
    eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat.<br />
    Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
    <br /><br />
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.<br />
    Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. 
    <br />Donec eu libero sit amet quam egesta semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. 
    <br />Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. 
    <br />Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. 
    <br /><br />
    Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci,<br />
    sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.<br />
    Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue,<br />
    eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat.<br />
    Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
    </p>

    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

And my css:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #28B04B;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 100%;
}
#head {
    height: 147px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 1297px;
}
#logo {
    background-image: url("images/logo.png");
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 147px;
    width: 297px;
}
#header {
    background-image: url("images/headbg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 147px;
    width: 1000px;
}
#menu {
    background-color: #d4efdb;
    border-bottom: 2px double #373C39;
    border-top: 2px double #373C39;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 320px;
}
#content {
    background-color: #e9f7ed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#txt {
    margin-left: 320px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#submnu {
    background-color: #d4efdb;
    width: 247px;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: block;
}
#scimg {
    background-image: url(images/scimg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 210px;
    height: 310px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

i have created a shopping cart (div id: scimg).
but when i watch it on a lower resolution. the div of the shopping cart flows OVER the context text. how can i fix that?
hope to hear from you soon!

Comment: don't change the original question create a new answer and reload the old question in this case for help other guys that have your ld problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add height:100%  at div content
See demo:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bvMHB/)

```
#content {
    background-color: #e9f7ed;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: if you have solved your problem with this answer accept it, this is how works stackoverflow @ashiekg